# Is there a way to control a desktop three.js based web app from phone?

Tags: javascript, socket.io, three.js, virtual-reality

I'm relatively new to javascript and totally novice about socket.io, I'm trying to navigate a web page VR based, on my desktop but gesturing on my phone. I've started with node.js and socket.io to connect device but i cannot undestand how I can convert touches on my phone to movements on desktop page. Thnx for the help

I'm running a express.js server and devices are connected, I'm able to show on desktop popup alert, text, touch coordinates.

Comment: [this project](https://github.com/greggman/hft-garden) is not currently in working condition and but you can look in the source, [see it pass orientation messages from the phone to the game](https://github.com/greggman/hft-garden/blob/29367b2292fa9bc69c1170d1ac6b326d91d86652/scripts/controller.js#L210). If you look in the game you can [see it use those messages to orient things in three.js](https://github.com/greggman/hft-garden/blob/29367b2292fa9bc69c1170d1ac6b326d91d86652/scripts/player.js#L253) in the browser.  [video of it working](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JtkSthVFFQc)

Comment: Thnx, i'll take a good look.